# How can I design a low pass filter using Z transform in Microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, laplace-transform, digital-filter

I have generated a signal which is a mixture of 50 Hz and 250 Hz sine waves using a microcontroller and DAC. Check the screenshot of the excel file: 
[image]

The values of row 4 (i.e. f1+f2) are feed to an 8-bit DAC to form the mixed signal. Now, if I read the Analog signal using another microcontroller at a 0.0002-second interval then I'll get back these data again.

So for the receiver, **x(n) = {120,132,144,155,163, ... ... , 90th value }.**
And the Z transform should be, **X(z) = {120 + 132z^(-1) + 144z^(-2) + 155z^(-3) + ... ... }**

Again, the transfer function of low pass RC filter is **H(s)= (1/(sRC+1)) = a(1/(s+a))**; where, **a= 1/RC**.

And the z transform will be **H(z) = a(z/(z- e^(-a)))**

So, how can I calculate the output response **Y(z) = X(z)H(z)**, as X(z) is a very long series. 
My aim is to use the output response equation in a microcontroller to reproduce the low-frequency signal.

Thanks in advance.

**It is solved according to the answer of @Warren Hill**
[image]

Comment: 4th column? The "D" column?

Comment: @Andyaka sorry row .. editing

Comment: I use this book: *The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing* by Steven W. Smith. Less theoretical and more practical than a classroom textbook. You don't have a lot of separation between 50 Hz and 250 Hz, you are going to need a higher order filter.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check that book.

Comment: @Mattman944 that book is very good. More interesting to read than textbooks.

Comment: If you choose an IIR (infinite impulse response) filter then you won't need to take many terms to obtain a decent low pass filter.

Comment: @Warren Hill has solved it. I've edited the question and given the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual method to design an IIR filter is to start with a frequency response we want, for example.

$$A(s)= \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{s}{\omega_p}}$$

Where \$ \omega_p \$ is the pole frequency in \$ \text{rad}\cdot \text{s}^{-1}\$.  We can convert this to time domain by using the Tustin or bi-linear transformation.

$$s = \dfrac{2}{T} \cdot \dfrac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}}$$

Where \$T\$ is the time between samples.  This gives us a new function in \$z\$

$$ H[z] = \dfrac{y}{x} = \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{2}{\omega_p\cdot T} \cdot \dfrac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}}}$$

With a bit or arithmetic we can get this of the form:

$$ H[z] = \dfrac{y}{x} = \dfrac{B_0+B_1 \cdot z^{-1} + B_2 \cdot z^{-2} + ... }{1-A_1 \cdot z^{-1} - A_2 \cdot z^{-2} - ...}$$

Now we note that \$ z^{-1} \$ represents one step back in time, \$ z^{-2} \$ represents two steps back in time and so on.

In this particular example we only need to worry about the the current a previous one values.

let \$y_0\$ be the current output, \$y_1\$ be the previous output, \$x_0\$ be the current input, \$x_1\$ be the previous input.

At each stage we can calculate a new \$y_0\$

$$y_0 = A_1 \cdot y_1 + B_0\cdot x_0 + B_1\cdot x_1$$

---

You can also design this as an FIR filter but because these do not look at previous outputs you would have significantly more terms.

$$y_0 = B_0 \cdot x_0 + B_1 \cdot x_1 + B_2 \cdot x_2 +  ...$$

Comment: Can you kindly explain what is A and B?

Comment: A and B are just numbers you when you rearrange the formula into the standard form.  I didn't want to calculate all the terms as I was showing the method.

Comment: o got it .. thanks

Comment: It has worked perfectly. Look at the edit of the question. I've included a screenshot of the result.

Answer (score 2):

> *How can I design a low pass filter using Z transform in
>   Microcontroller?*

A simple IIR 1st order filter can be designed like this from [here](http://www.jamesoakwood.co.uk/Digital%20filter%20design%20for%20Analogue%20engineers.pdf?LMCL=a70U_p): -

[image]